# "give full scope to" VS "give full play to"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> 1. we will be able to **give full scope to** the advantages of A, B and C and further strengthen their cooperation and enable the three to draw on each other's strength.
> 2. we will be able to **give full play to** the advantages of A, B and C and further strengthen their cooperation and enable the three to draw on each other's strength.

A, B C refer to three provinces of China. Is it legimate to use the phases "give full scope to" and "give full play to" in the above sentences.

And is "give full scope to" have the same meaning as "give full play to"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, they are synonyms.

According to [this dictionary](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/give%20full%20play/en-en/) the synonyms of give full play are:

> give a free hand, give free play, **give full scope**, leave be, leave
>   free, leave to his own devices